# How to cite preprints from arXiv?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-software, publishing

Obviously when writing a math research paper it is good to cite one's references. However, with the advent of arXiv, oftentimes a paper is only available on arXiv while is awaits the long process of peer-review. But here a problem arises: how does one cite an arXiv preprint?

Note: I would be nice if a bibTeX template was included.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/how-to-cite-an-article-from-arxiv-using-bibtex

Comment: You could use the Arxiv to solve this question: the source files are usually available under "Other formats".

Comment: I saw this. Most of the answers weren't very useful IMO.

Comment: Made CW by request.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the to the url, for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00573

On the right under References & Citations click the link for "NASA ADS"

Scroll down under the abstract and click the link for "Bibtex entry for this abstract"

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any reason for treating preprints on arxiv in references differently, so you should do the same thing as what you would do for a preprint found on the author's webpage.

Personally, I would simply put `NOTE = {preprint, \url{http://arxiv.org/abs/****}}` in the bibtex entry. (You also need `\usepackage{url}` in your main tex-file, if you use this syntax. If your bibtex style supports url field, it would be  put the url there.)

BTW by checking a few results when [searching for "preprint arxiv"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22preprint+arxiv%22) in Google Books or from this Scholar Google search: ["preprint arxiv" site:springer.com](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=%22preprint+arxiv%22+site:springer.com) you can see, that there are other people using similar convention.

EDIT: After adding this answer I've noticed that it is basically the same thing as Willy Wong's suggestion from TeX.SE thread linked in Marvis' comment:
[How to cite an article from Arxiv using bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/how-to-cite-an-article-from-arxiv-using-bibtex).

Answer (score 6):

Whatever you do, make sure that some semblance of the arXiv citation string appears in your citation. By that I mean either the full url  (random example from a tab I have open)

```
https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2525
```

or the [suggested arXiv citation format in BibTeX](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles) which would print something like

```
arXiv:1205.2525 [math.CA]
```

in the citations. One of the many points of a citation is to tell people where to look for the paper, therefore you should include necessary information as to where to search.

Also, as arXiv papers are mutable, it may be a good idea to cite the specific revision of a paper that you consulted if it has multiple. That would append `v#` where `#` is a numeral to the arXiv citation string.